# iOS NSArray count

Tags: ios, objective-c

I think my question is simple but it stumped me. Basically I have a NSArray of objects for example:

```
NSArray *arrayT = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", nil];
```

I want to put these objects into a TableViewCell. To display, I did

```
cell.positioninarray.text = [arrayT objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.letterinarray.text = [arrayT objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I am expecting this result

```
1      A
2      B
3      C
4      D
```

But am getting

```
A      A
B      B
C      C
D      D
```

I've looked through the NSArray help file in Apple developer website, but i don't see one that works for me.

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cell.positioninarray.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)(indexPath.row+1)];
```

Comment: Don't forgot to +1 the indexPath.row!

Comment: Beat a lot of people apparently :P

Comment: Hey Tamas, I saw your answer - thanks but it does not indicate where to get the indexPath from. Shouldn't there be arrayT indicated in the code somewhere?

Comment: I've tried running it but it worked! Could you tell me why this would work without indicating arrayT?

Comment: Hey @user2135737, the code that you have written in your question is probably inside the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Since you only want the positions of the array elements, you don't need `arrayT` anywhere. The `indexPath.row` will give the index of the current cell in which you are setting the text, so it will work.

Comment: This is great! Now i know better. Please - could you share with me on where you had learnt this from? I'm pulling my hair out trying to learn Objective C!

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
cell.positioninarray.text = [arrayT objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

with

```
cell.positioninarray.text = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%d", ((int)indexPath.row+1)];
```

---

#### Explanation

You are setting the text for both `positioninarray` and `letterinarray` to be

```
[arrayT objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

So you are getting `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` in both of the labels. To get `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` in `positioninarray`, use the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below, `indexPath.row` will give you current index for the cell, and you want position start by `1` not `0` so `indexPath.row + 1` will do your work, and finally convert your int value to string using `NSString stringWithFormat` :

```
cell.positioninarray.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (indexPath.row + 1)];
cell.letterinarray.text = [arrayT objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```